# keyboard randomly repeating keystroke when plugged in

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, hardware-failure, battery

My keyboard keep randomly repeat my keystrokes. Any key could be repeated, sometimes twice, sometimes 3 times or more, no pattern at all. When I remove the keyboard and plug it in another computer, it work just fine. The built-in keyboard of the laptop also have no issue. Also, it ONLY happens when I have the laptopp plugged in to a power source. If I run it on battery power, nothing is out of place.

I've tried restarting the computer, enable filter key and changing the delay setting for the keystroke, physically removingg the battery, reinstall the keyboard driver, drain the battery completely then hold the power button for more than 30s to drain the remaining electricity before replugging and turning the thing on... but nothing work! The only way for it to work like normal is to unplug the laptop and use it on battery, which is highly disruptive to my workflow.

Could someone help please?

Some techcnical info:

- OS: Windows 10 Home (64 bit)
- Laptop brand: ASUS
- Processor: Intel Core i5 -2450M CPU @2.50GHz
- Keyboard brand: HTC Keyboard (plugged in through an USB port)

Comment: I had a similar issue a while back and was never able to determine precisely what the issue was.  Are you on the most recent version of Win10 _(v1903, as v1909 Stable is released in Oct)_?  If not, updating will likely resolve the issue since the way the bi-annual updates are installed are similar to a repair install of Windows.  If the keyboard has drivers, ensure they're also updated via the manufacturer's website.

Comment: Yes, i'm on the latest windows 10 version. And as far as I can tell, the driver for my keyboard is also the latest version. Did the problem just randomly go away for you after updating windows or did you have to do something else?

Comment: What model of keyboard is it exactly? Is it maybe a touch keyboard of some kind?

Comment: No, it's this kind of keyboard: https://www.lazada.vn/-i121015746-s121062556.html?urlFlag=true&mp=1

And the problem most likely does not lie with the keyboard. As I have stated, it work just fine when I plug it in another computer, and when I'm using it on battery power. Only when I plug the power cable (not sure if this is the right wordr for it) in the laptop will the problem appear

Comment: @LongTran The issue did go away after a bi-annual update, and my hunch is it was due to the process by which the bi-annual updates are installed, effectively making them a repair install of Windows.  An issue like this could take hours to troubleshoot or only an hour, so if the user doesn't have a lot of programs installed, I always recommend a reinstall of Windows since it only takes ~2hrs to reinstall windows, install CPU drivers, run Windows update, then install software.  If you want to troubleshoot, I would do so on the SpiceWorks or MSFN forums due to the knowledge of their users.

Comment: @LongTran I asked because power adapters with grounding issues oftentimes cause touch screen problems like ghost touches etc., it can be observed on some mobile phones when charged with cheap adapters. Anyway, sounds like I was on a right track. Glad to hear you've found the solution!

Answer (score 3):

I FOUND THE PROBLEM!

The issue is my AC Adapter. Apparently, the voltage or something along that line isn't what it's supposed to be. Replacing it and everything work just fine. If anyone's having this problem in the future, try replacing your adapter.

If you don't want to shell out the dough yet, try these steps first to be absolutely certain it's a hardware problem:

- charge battery to full
- search for *Typing settings*
- go to *Bluetooth & other devices*
- pick the keyboard and choose *Remove device*
- restart, and let the driver for the keyboard reinstall

OR

- charge battery to full (or until it can last a bit after unplugging)
- unplug the power cord
- let the battery completely drain, and the computer shut down
- remove the battery
- hold the power button for >30 sec
- plug the power cord in and turn it back on

If the problem persists, you'll have to at least have a technician look at it.